# Server client in c support non-bounded string

Tags: c, linux, udp, client

I have a client-server project over UDP pass string from client and server and vice versa. I want to pass unbounded length of strings between the server to the client, I thought about a solution in which the  server puts an `ETX` char at buffer[strlen(buffer)+1] to indicate the client there is more buffers to come and that the client doesn't need to close the connection and wait for more data to come.

1. Is it a good idea to design the mechanism like that?
2. Is there a better solution (I want to avoid declare a convention of  )
3. How `C#`/`java` will handle `ETX` char if it needs to print it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to design it like that?

It depends. You said that you want to use UDP. How will you handle packets that are lost or that are received out of order?

> Is there a better solution (I want to avoid declare a convention of )

If you want to send a continuous stream it's easier to just use TCP.

> How C#/java will handle ETX char if it needs to print it?

They will almost surely print it as the control character that it is. It can be displayed as a blank or as a square for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass an unbounded string I don't think UDP is the best protocoll. With UDP sockets, you can get a package multiple times, out of order or not at all. For a string you most probably would want to use a TCP socket.

if you want to use a special character then you must either ensure that this character is never used in the actual string data. Or if it can be used, you must mask it somehow on the sender side and then unmask it on the receiver side, which means you have some kind of protocoll. If you know, on the sender side, how long the string will be, it's probably easier to send the length first, and then the string itself. Or you could simply close the connection when you are done. Depends on what you are actually trying to achieve.